# Converting Maven dependency to Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, pom.xml

I am currently following a tutorial [here](https://automationrhapsody.com/running-cucumber-tests-in-parallel/) and saw a POM plugin that I couldn't convert to Gradle, you can find the plugin below. Tried to follow a couple tutorials though they didn't seem to help, the part I am confused about is the executions and what is the general syntax that Gradle expects.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0</version>

  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generateRunners</id>
      <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>generateRunners</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <!-- Mandatory -->
        <!-- List of package names to scan for glue code. -->
        <glue>
          <package>com.example</package>
          <package>com.example.other</package>
        </glue>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: maybe this Gradle plugin is the equivalent of the Maven plugin you want to use: https://github.com/camiloribeiro/cucumber-gradle-parallel

Comment: this dependency version in gradle was downloaded fine for me - I havent tested the commands though 
`compile group: 'com.github.temyers', name: 'cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin', version: '2.2.0'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [version 4.x cucumber supports parallel execution](https://cucumber.io/blog/2018/09/24/announcing-cucumber-jvm-4-0-0). This makes the `cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin` for maven obsolete.

You'll will have to create a  task that uses gradles `JavaExec` to call [cucumbers CLI](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/api/cli/Main.java) directly with `--parallel 4`.

I don't believe you can use Cucumbers JUnit runner with Gradle to achieve parallel execution because Gradle doesn't install a parallel computer into JUnit but instead forks the the JVM.